# Windows 8 Metro App Freezes on Resume?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, freeze

I am working on a Metro Style App for Windows 8. If I go to the start screen and back to my two main pages, they freeze.

The simpler of the two pages contains only a text box, a button, a few text blocks, and a few hyperlink buttons. The text box displays and sets settings.

I have no code in the resuming or suspending events, and the resuming event doesn't fire anyway.

Nothing unusual appears in the debugger. A new blank page works fine on resume, but upon copying the xaml from the old pages, the problem continues. Has anyone experienced this problem before. I understand this is not much information, but I cannot find any additional details.

Comment: You should pare down your xaml until you have the minimum necessary to make it crash and then post it here.

Comment: Did you debugger hit the OnNavigated to event? If yet, check your codes within that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue, I found the solution. The problem was in the c#, not the xaml. I used Dispatcher.RunAsync to run the same method over and over again.

```
void Animate()
{
    ...
    Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, new DispatchedHandler(Animate));
}
```

I used a DispatcherTimer instead, and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think last time I saw something like that - restarting Windows helped, but checking if the app ever gets restarted in the debugger would certainly help. You could check if the Window.Current.Activated event fires.

Comment: Restarting didn't help, but the Activated event does fire.